# Rails commands in home directory result in "i18n gem is not available" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, rails-i18n

I was in my Ubuntu home directory, trying to create a new rails app with `rails new`, but I got this error:

> The i18n gem is not available. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install

Any rails command I run gives that error. I'm really confused, because I'm not inside an application. I'm just in my home directory. There is no gemfile. I tried installing 'i18n' into my home directory with `gem install 'i18n'`, and it worked, but I'm still getting that error.

I've never had any problems with rails commands in my home directory before. Everything rails-related works normally when I `cd` into my individual apps. What's going on?

**Also**, I'm now getting the same error in all my existing rails apps. Did rails suddenly become reliant on that gem? Or could deleting the gem in my home directory somehow have made it unavailable in my apps?

---

### UPDATE

I tried `gem cleanup rails` and reinstalling, but nothing changed. Here was the result:

```
$ gem cleanup rails
  Cleaning up installed gems...
  Attempting to uninstall rails-4.0.10
  Successfully uninstalled rails-4.0.10
  Attempting to uninstall rails-4.2.1
  Successfully uninstalled rails-4.2.1
  Attempting to uninstall rails-4.2.4
  Successfully uninstalled rails-4.2.4
  Attempting to uninstall rails-5.0.1
  Successfully uninstalled rails-5.0.1
  Attempting to uninstall rails-5.0.2
  Successfully uninstalled rails-5.0.2
  Attempting to uninstall rails-5.0.3
  Successfully uninstalled rails-5.0.3
  Attempting to uninstall rails-5.0.4
  Successfully uninstalled rails-5.0.4
  Clean Up Complete
$ gem install rails -v 5.0.1
  Fetching: rails-5.0.1.gem (100%)
  Successfully installed rails-5.0.1
  Parsing documentation for rails-5.0.1
  Installing ri documentation for rails-5.0.1
  Done installing documentation for rails after 1 seconds
  1 gem installed
$ rails -v
  The i18n gem is not available. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install
```

---

### UPDATE 2

I had previously manually installed `i18n` and I thought that might be the problem so I uninstalled both `rails` and `i18n` and reinstalled `rails`. But I'm still getting the error:

```
  $ gem uninstall rails --all

You have requested to uninstall the gem:
    rails-5.0.1

browser-2.3.0 depends on rails (>= 0, development)
browser-1.1.0 depends on rails (>= 0, development)
browser-0.9.1 depends on rails (>= 0, development)
carrierwave-1.2.1 depends on rails (>= 4.0.0, development)
carrierwave-1.0.0 depends on rails (>= 4.0.0, development)
rails_serve_static_assets-0.0.5 depends on rails (>= 3.1, development)
rails_serve_static_assets-0.0.4 depends on rails (>= 3.1, development)
sass-rails-4.0.5 depends on rails (>= 0, development)
sunspot_rails-2.2.7 depends on rails (>= 3)
twitter-typeahead-rails-0.10.5 depends on rails (>= 3.1, development)
yaml_db_improved-1.0.1 depends on rails (>= 0)
If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [yN]  y
Successfully uninstalled rails-5.0.1

  $ gem uninstall i18n --all

You have requested to uninstall the gem:
    i18n-0.9.1

activesupport-5.1.4 depends on i18n (~> 0.7)
activesupport-5.0.5 depends on i18n (~> 0.7)
activesupport-5.0.4 depends on i18n (~> 0.7)
activesupport-5.0.3 depends on i18n (~> 0.7)
activesupport-5.0.2 depends on i18n (~> 0.7)
activesupport-5.0.1 depends on i18n (~> 0.7)
activesupport-4.2.4 depends on i18n (~> 0.7)
activesupport-4.2.1 depends on i18n (~> 0.7)
activesupport-4.0.10 depends on i18n (>= 0.6.9, ~> 0.6)
capistrano-3.8.0 depends on i18n (>= 0)
capistrano-3.7.2 depends on i18n (>= 0)
If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [yN]  y
Successfully uninstalled i18n-0.9.1

  $ gem install rails --version 5.0.1

Fetching: i18n-0.9.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.9.1
Fetching: rails-5.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-5.0.1
Parsing documentation for i18n-0.9.1
Installing ri documentation for i18n-0.9.1
Parsing documentation for rails-5.0.1
Installing ri documentation for rails-5.0.1
Done installing documentation for i18n, rails after 4 seconds
2 gems installed

  $ rails -v

The i18n gem is not available. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2278:in `check_version_conflict': can't activate activesupport-5.1.4, alrea
...
```

Comment: can you see where your `i18n` gem is installed doing `bundle show i18n` ?

Comment: @Subash That command returns this: "Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory"

Comment: It looks like an issue with your ruby/rails environment, can you do `ruby -v` and what are you using to manage your rubies, `rvm` or `rebnv` ?

Comment: @Subash Yes "ruby -v" returns the expected output of "ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux]". I'm using rvm.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling everything and check with a fresh install

Comment: @Subash Would uninstalling rails on my home directory affect any of my current rails applications?

Comment: it would not affect any existing applications. They will have rails installed via bundler and their Gemfile. Also you can just as easily re-install any version of rails you might need

Comment: Be sure to confirm that `ruby -v`, `rails -v` and `bundle -v` outputs the expected versions since Rails could be using a different gemset.

Comment: What is the output of `gem list -de rails activesupport i18n` in your home directory? I'd also try `gem pristine i18n rails`, probably to no avail since reinstall failed. If all fails, I'd remove all rubies, rvm and related directories and install from scratch (shouldn't affect any other existing code in any other folder, you'd just need to bundle again).

Comment: What do you get with `which -a ruby`

Comment: I started getting this after control-C on a `rails new` command. I guess that messed something up. `gem install rails` did work though.

Answer (score 6):

Try `gem install rails` again. Or `gem install rails -v 5.0` to install a specific version.

It appears you somehow don't have rails and it's dependencies fully installed. Perhaps because you reinstalled ruby or installed a different ruby version. If i'm right that's what's going on, just reinstall the latest version of rails or the version you want, and everything needed will be there again.

Comment: I ran `gem install rails -v 5.0.1` and terminal said it was successfully installed, but any rails command still returns the error about missing the `i18n` gem, and needing to add it to my gemfile.

Answer (score 2):

<del>Are you using any version manager, `rvm` or `rbenv`? You should use this to prevent any mismatch in installing libraries and ensuring your packages are ordered.</del>

I will suggest you to remove anything Ruby related and install Rbenv first. A quick search with that error, I found it mostly relates to RVM. I could be wrong though but try with Rbenv. Use Rbenv to setup Ruby in your Ubuntu. Here is a link for [Rbenv in Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Also, why not try to create a Gemfile and actually add `gem 'i18n', '~> 0.7.0'`.

Then run `bundle install`. If it says it is gem locked, use `bundle update i18n`

What does it say?

And also, what do you get with `which -a ruby`

Answer (score 1):

You might have multiple versions of rails installed. Maybe try running `gem cleanup rails`

For more information on the command see `gem cleanup --help`

Edit: and then of course you'd have to install rails again. Either latest stable version or whichever you prefer.

**UPDATE**

Looking at your output of `gem install` it doesn't seem to install any of the dependencies, so it assumes you have i18n installed already.

Here is what you can do:

1. Check out which versions you have installed. Run `gem list | grep i18n` and `grep rails` respectively.
2. Remove all versions of these gems via `gem uninstall i18n --all` and `gem uninstall rails --all` respectively
3. Install rails `gem install rails --version 5.0.1` and it should output `Successfully installed i18n-0.9.1` during the install process.

Here's my output:

```
# blank slate
$ rails -v
Rails is not currently installed on this system.

# successful rails install
$ gem install rails -v 5.0.1
...
Fetching: i18n-0.9.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.9.1
...
35 gems installed

# verify installed gems
$ gem list | grep rails
rails (5.0.1)
...
$ gem list | grep i18n
i18n (0.9.1)

# break i18n
$ gem uninstall i18n --all

You have requested to uninstall the gem:
i18n-0.9.1

activesupport-5.0.1 depends on i18n (~> 0.7)
If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [yN]  y
Successfully uninstalled i18n-0.9.1

$ rails -v
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:308:in `to_specs': Could not find 'i18n' (~> 0.7) among 51 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)

# fix i18n and rails
$ gem uninstall rails --all
Successfully uninstalled rails-5.0.1
$ gem uninstall i18n --all
$ gem install rails --version 5.0.1
Fetching: i18n-0.9.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.9.1
Fetching: rails-5.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-5.0.1
2 gems installed

# working again
$ rails -v
Rails 5.0.1
```

Comment: I did that, and it seemed to work at first, but then I got the same error as soon as I tried to do anything with my newly-installed rails. I added all the output in my question.

Comment: I tried uninstalling both i18n and rails and reinstalling rails, but I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

So I still don't understand exactly what was happening, but I uninstalled rails using `gem uninstall rails` and then reinstalled it with just `gem install rails`, and rails commands now work. Apparently the problem wasn't even really related to i18n. I'm at a total loss. At least it works now!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with i8ln in the the place where ruby is installed.

For example

`Ruby2.3.3\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems`

Try to reinstall ruby and try.

Make sure you clear all ruby files before you do a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error after a messy merge on a rails 6.1.4.7 project.

I ran `gem uninstall rails` , switched the rails version to 7.0.4 in the Gemfile and ran `bundle update`. After that, all rails commands seem to be working fine.